# Meteor Router.go() doesn't rederect, but it works in Chrome's console

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Meteor Router.go() doesn't work. It just flash a new url for few milliseconds in the browser, and the page didn't switch.

Sorry I can't find any clue how this wired thing happen..!

```
Template.Post.events({ 
'click a': function() { 
    Router.go('mainPage');  
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'mainPage',
  template: 'mainPage'
});
```

Update: I input Router.go('mainPage'); in Chrome console. It works and return undefined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To avoid this miserable, horrible experience for everyone, let me post my solution and answer myself:

When `Router.go()` redirects the URL, the URL also instantly redirects to `href="#"` or `href=""`. Thus, it disables the redirection from `Router.go()`.

The way to solve it is just to NOT put `href=""` in the `<a>` tag. Also, you can add this css:

```
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

to show that the tag is actually clickable.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me so much time !

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid having to remove the `href` by calling `event.preventDefault()` which stops the execution of any additional bubbled events like the `href` click:

```
"click #aLinkId": function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Router.go('/newLocation');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too, wrapping it in Meteor.setTimeout was the only way to make it work.

```
'click a': function() { 
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){ Router.go('mainPage'); }, 10); 
}
```

Comment: that's amazing...but have you found out why this wired thing happen?

Comment: It seems there is a problem on ```<a>``` when it has ```href``` attribute. You need to specify ```e.preventDefault()```, look here https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1038

Comment: Oh GREAT!!! That's it!! Once remove the href in <a> Router.go works!! It is a horrible bug!

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your Router definitions?

At least setup one route:

```
Router.route('/mainPage', {
    template: 'mainPage'
});
```

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md

Comment: I have read it. I just can't find why it doesn't work...  I input Router.go('mainPage') in Chrome console and It works perfect and return undefined.

Comment: As far as I can see your syntax for the events is not correct (Template.Post.events({})).

Comment: If you can make a reproduction of the error, I can have a closer look.